# Module opens article in same window with existing modules instead of new page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I created a new menu (v. 2.5) with an extension.  I treated the objects in the new menu as a new article and linked to them using the menu manager. So clicking on a menu item opens up a new page called "x".

The new page ("x") opens up from the new menu bar with module items (like pictures) appearing. I want to add a link to yet an additional page and have it pop up.  The page opens up, but appears at the bottom of the existing page with all of the other modules showing. Not a pop up, not a new clean article without pictures from the modules in "x". So, instead of just having a text article in a new window, it opens up in the middle of all the existing modules on that page.

I tried to use the "open in another window" in the link manager of the module manager, but it doesn't work.  I'm lost.

Comment: please, can you provide a link to your site and which menu entry we should look at?

Answer (score 0):

The modules in Joomla system are assigned to Menu elements. Please go to Extensions/Module Manager. You will se the published modules here. There is a column on this list called Pages. If you see All it means this module will appears on every pages.

The solution is open the modules one by one and scroll down to Menu Assign and set where you want to see the module.